# How to save a record using a background worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, redis, resque

If I am saving a video file onto the server that is greater than 5mb. Should I create a background job for saving this file?

How should this be done? My video model has a title, description and attachment columns/fields. All fields are required.

In def create, instead of doing **"if @video.save"**, I should do something like **"if Resque.enqueue(Save, @video)"**?

I am not exactly sure how this can be done, since passing an argument to Resque.enqueue() turns it into a hash. Second, with " **"if Resque.enqueue(Save, @video)"**", expects a true or false. However, Resque.enqueue can't return anything. Or am I wrong?

Button line is. What is the appropriate way to save a record using a background worker with resque + redis?

Ideally, I was thinking it should look something similar to:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(params[:video])

  respond_to do |format|
    if Resque.enqueue(Save)
      ...
    end
end

module Save
  @queue = :save

  def self.perform
    video = Video.new(params[:video])
    video.save
    return true
  end
end
```

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realising the situation again. I dont think uploaders are meant to have delayed jobs.. think about it. what happens if  an upload file is queued at the 10nth position. Where does it expect to get the file from?

As quoted by another dev: "There are HTTP request handlers and just background processes. You need to handle the original upload in a http request handler and THEN you can fire up an external background process to upload it to S3 form the local disk".

Which means, it is normal to have a few HTTP request handlers running initially to handle these types of requests.

Hope this clears up a few things for users who end up coming across the same concern.

Answer (score 0):

I would have users upload an UnencodedVideo. Then, on its create method, it starts a job to encode the video (using resque/delayedjobs), which will create a Video.

```
class UnencodedVideo
  def after_create
    Resque.enqueue(Encoder, this.id)
  end
end

class Encoder
  def self.perform(unencoded_video_id)
    unencoded_video = UnencodedVideo.find(unencoded_video_id)
    ...
    video.save
  end
end

class Video
end
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, yea, I currently have it like that. But if I allow the end-user to upload an unencoded video first, then this will take up a single process. So basically, if I have 2 users browsing the site. User foobar decides to upload. Then the application freezes, until foobar's upload completes. Rendering the application unusable for the second user. Or not? My webhost is Heroku. In this particular situation I would need to have > 1 dynos. Am I right?

Comment: Ahhh, ok, so the problem is the uploading, right? You should have users upload directly to S3 then and process it in the background later. Read http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 and https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin

Comment: Hi Jesse. Yeap we are already uploading to S3. The links you suggested are still doing everything in the foreground. Which will still take up a dyno/per upload/per user. I just need to know, if an end-user uploads, should I have it as a background job or not? What is the general consensus? We expect several users in our app to upload video content at any given time. It's quite expensive to have several dynos running at once. I would rather have a background job for this. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Christian -- the S3 uploader will upload directly to S3. The normal path is to upload to the server, and the server posts to s3. This way keeps your servers responsive with no upload to heroku.

Comment: Hi Jesse, but thats the thing. Uploading directly to S3 doesn't mean it happens in the background. It still takes up a single web process

Comment: Christian -- uploading directly means the web server connects directly to S3. there is no web process in Rails.

Comment: Jesse, this means the application won't hang until the upload is finished?

Comment: Correct, the application won't know there is an upload going on until the browser has uploaded to S3.